# Deep Link in push notification navigating to App Store :- Problem with deep linking

Tags: swift, push-notification, deep-linking

I have a platform called net core which is an external source for sending push notification. The problem is that when I put the link in the notification and try to open the app by clicking the push notification. The link is not opening in the app, it is navigating to safari.

Is there a way to open the link in the app from push notification and open the specific view controller based on the data present in the link?

Guys any solution on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible

First of all, you should send URL correct way(in the data section of notification)

Then in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

you need to get this URL from `userInfo` parameter(which is your notification)

Keep URL like this

```
var urlToOpen: String?
```

in AppDelegate

Then in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method, you should check if `urlToOpen` is not nil and if not parse it as you wish and do anything you want(eg open specific ViewController or some other stuff).

p.s.

Don't forget to set `urlToOpen` to nil at the end of `applicationDidBecomeActive` method

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ilya Stukalov